# Range key with a timestamp. Query and pagination with DynamoDB

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm confused. How should I design a DynamoDB table to effectively query items using reverse order of timestamps with pagination?

I know I can use `ScanIndexForward` and query it with `Limit` and `LastEvaluatedKey` but the guide says: "Query results are always sorted by the range key, based on ASCII character code values"

What the range key should contain then? Right now I'm using reverseTimestamp, but I'm not sure that this:

```
var request = new QueryRequest()
    .WithTableName("Output")
    .WithLimit(25)
    .WithScanIndexForward(false)
    .WithExclusiveStartKey(new Key { HashKeyElement = new AttributeValue {S = "1"}, 
     RangeKeyElement = new AttributeValue {S = lastKeyEvaluated} })
```

will return 25 latest items in the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python's DynamoDB-Mapper, we serialize all dates to "W3C Date/Time Format" AKA "RFC 3339". It has the nice property to sort times in the right order when using UTF-8 text sort. Another side effect is to store tz info with the timestamp.

Comment: yeah I see... now `AWSSDKUtils` has a few types `GMTDateFormat`, `ISO8601BasicDateTimeFormat` ,`ISO8601DateFormat` ,`ISO8601DateFormatNoMS`, `RFC822DateFormat` ,`UrlEncodedContent`... which should I use? And it doesn't have the one you're mentioning

Comment: @Agzam: RFC3339 is a subset of **ISO8601**. Pick the variant you want depending on you needs.